# Which is better to use: "добраться к" or "добраться до"?

Tags: словоупотребление, предлоги, phrase

As far as I can tell `добраться` means "to get to (somewhere/place)".

However, since it's a reflexive verb, in order to take an additional "object", it needs to have a preposition following it. (Unless one has a special-purpose adverb, as in the case of `добраться домой`). It is unclear to me which preposition is better used here, `к` or `до`.

Specifically, `добраться к` and `добраться до` both seem to be synonymous to me.

> **Question:** Which is better to use: `добраться к` or `добраться до`?

The choice of whether to use `к` or `до` does not seem to depend on the type of destination. I have seen both `добраться к нам` and `добраться до нас` to mean "to reach us/arrive at where we are", i.e. for arriving at a place defined by some person/people's presence there. I have also seen both used for arriving at a place defined intrinsically, i.e. by name but not by a person's presence or absence there, e.g. `добраться к аэропорту` and `добраться до аэропорта`.

(Compare: `Она ходила к нам, поэтому она была у нас` and `Она ходила в аэропорт, поэтому она была в аэропорту` -- the different types of locations demand different prepositions.)

The word `добраться` is new to me, and I don't think it is as likely that I will use it correctly in the future if I don't learn it with a corresponding preposition. But I am not sure which phrase would be better to put on my flash cards: `добраться к` or `добраться до`.

Comment: Note that they are not always interchangeable. And in many cases (maybe in most) "добраться к" and "добраться до" have slightly different meanings. So "добраться до аэропорта/города/дома" is not exactly the same as "добраться к аэропорту/городу/дому".

Comment: @Akaban would you mind explaining in an answer what the difference in meaning is? I honestly have no idea.

Comment: (_I don't think it would be enough for an answer_) Generally, "добраться до" has broader meaning of arriving, reaching smth., etc. Saying "я добрался до аэропорта" you say that you arrived at the airport. Saying "я добрался к аэропорту" you say that you arrived at the airport but not entered it yet (you stay at the entrance door or are still in the car).

Answer (score 4):

The exact semantic difference eludes me but one thing is for sure: **добраться до** is 30 times as frequent as **добраться к** according to [ruscorpora.ru](http://ruscorpora.ru). So use **до** and you'll be right 30:1.

Answer (score 2):

By default and when required, a verb with a prefix is used in a same-topic utterance with an existing modern preposition similar to a prefix (unless semantics and/or usage require it to be otherwise). Not sure if with works with inanimate complements only or otherwise:

***Зайти за деньгами.***

***Набрести на клад.***

***Довести до ума.***

With your examples, both options are correct, but there are some different nuances of meaning.

***к нам*** means spatially a location 'where we are' in a sense similar to the French *'chez nous'* (a place where we abide and which is ours);

***до нас*** means spatially a location 'where we are' in a sense 'a place where we are located now and which is not ours'

This difference seems to work with animate compliments only. E. g. one cannot say about inanimate complements * ***'дойти к двери'*** or * '***дойти к городу***' (but the rare or possible usage of ***дойти + к*** can also be explained by the aforementioned nuances as well).

Comment: I agree with you on the difference between 'my place' and 'my current location' which apparently only works with animate compliments. But there are also lots of example of **добраться к** with inanimate objects: _На впрысковых двигателях добраться к фильтру сложнее._, _Нам предстояло до темноты добраться к подножию сопки_, etc, etc. See http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E4%EE%E1%F0%E0%F2%FC%F1%FF%20%EA&p=4

Comment: So it seems that it's the topic that's relevant, not quality of a complement being animate/inanimate. I deduce this from the fact that in both examples you have quoted there must be some change in topic / rhema of the sentences. E. g. the first sentence is likely to follow a description of motors the type of which differs from the injective ones. The second sentence is rather to be an end of a paragraph than to be followed by a discription of the hill.